# How to Automatically close a specific window when windows starts?

Tags: autohotkey

Hy, I'am a newbie in autohotkey.
I have a specific program that I made It start automatically when Windows starts, and this program works by default in the system tray icon.

The program is :

The window title : LilySpeech Settings

The process name : ahk_exe LilySpeech64-1.exe

The problem is :

When the program starts automatically when Windows starts, it works by default in the system icon, but the window of the program appears and It stills appear on the screen Every time I start Windows.

- I want the window of the program to be closed automatically and only every time I start Windows, knowing that if I close the program window the program continues to work in the system tray icon and this is what I want.
- I'm looking for an AHK script to do that.
- Note : I'm using AHK V1.1.36.02.
- I've tried this but didn't work:

  ```
    Loop {
        WinWaitActive ahk_exe LilySpeech64-1.exe
        WinClose ahk_exe LilySpeech64-1.exe
    }
  ```
- Please help! I appreciate your time and effort. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you set the startup to start minimized? This iften forces a program to start, then minimize, and most programs that minimize to system tray automatically hide the window. You can set this from the shortcut, and if you place that shortcut in your startup (type shell:startup) in the adressbar of your file explorer to get there.

Answer (score 1):

To configure a script to start automatically after the user logs in, the easiest way is to place a shortcut to the script file in the Startup folder.

Full path of the Startup folder:
`C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Try this code:

```
WinWait, LilySpeech Settings
WinClose, LilySpeech Settings
WinWaitClose, LilySpeech Settings,, 5 ; 5 seconds to wait
If ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, Could not close LilySpeech Settings
```

Comment: You can also jump to startup by running "shell:startup" or typing that it into the Explorer bar to navigate there